# Calculating different bands of overtime in php

Tags: php

This is my first time posting here so I'm sorry if I get something wrong. I'm trying to calculate how many hours overtime a worker has worked based on when they signed in. The problem is that we have different bands of overtime:

- If the worker works between 5 and 7 then it's 25% extra per hour
- If they worked between 7pm and 10pm then its 50% extran for each hour
- If the worker works between 10 and 12 then it's 75% extra
- If the worker works between 12am and 7am is 100% more

I need to count how many hours they worked at each of the overtime bands

```
$number_of_25_percent_hours=0;
$number_of_50_percent_hours=0;
$number_of_75_percent_hours=0;
$number_of_100_percent_hours=0;

$clockInTime=$arr['4'];
$clockOutTime=$arr['5'];


$startingPieces=explode(':',$clockInTime);
$startingHour=$startingPieces[0];


$finishingPieces=explode(':',$clockInTime);
$finishingHour=$finishingPieces[0];


//Regular hours are between 7am and and 5pm


//If the worker works between 5 and 7 then it's 25% extra per hour
       if(($startingHour<=5)&&($finishingHour>=6)){$number_of_25_percent_hours++;}
       if(($startingHour<=6)&&($finishingHour>=7)){$number_of_25_percent_hours++;}
```

The problem with using the lines above is that it does not work if for example they worked an hour from 6:30 to 7:30.

I'm interested in finding other ways to do this.

Comment: Are you missing a $ before startingHour and finishingHour?

Answer (score 0):

you need to store the data more exactly. From your script it looks as if you were only saving the starting hour - which propably is a full number (1,2,3,4 whatsoever)

You script however needs a exact time representation. There are surely many ways to do this but for the sake of a better Script (and as you will propably be able to use some of these more exact values later on) I'd recommend you to store it as a UNIX Timestamp, then get the hour of the Timestamp :

```
$startingHour = date('H' $timeStampStored)
```

and check if it's in any of your "bonus" segments. If the user started working at 6:30, the value will hold 6.

Answer (score 0):

This code is completely off the top of my head, untested etc. It's intended as a suggestion of one method you might use to solve the problem, not as a robust example of working code. It uses integers instead of dates, relies on array data being entered in order etc, and probably wouldn't even run.

The basic idea is to set up the scales for each level of overtime multiplier, as well as the hours for non-overtime pay in an array, then loop through that array checking how many hours of each level of overtime have been worked between the inputted times, meanwhile keeping track of a total billable hours value.

```
$PayMultipliers = array();
$PayMultipliers[0] = array(17,19,1.25);
$PayMultipliers[1] = array(19,22,1.5);
$PayMultipliers[2] = array(22,24,1.75);
$PayMultipliers[3] = array(0,7,1.5);
$PayMultipliers[4] = array(7, 17, 1);

$Start = 3;
$End = 11;
$TotalHours = 0;

for($i = 0; $i <= count($PayMultipliers); $i++)
{
    if($Start > $PayMultipliers[$i][0] && $Start < $PayMultipliers[$i][1])
    {
        $TotalHours += ($PayMultipliers[$i][1] - $Start) * $PayMultipliers[$i][2];
        $Start = $PayMultipliers[$i][1];
    }
}

echo $TotalHours;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate from 6:30 to 7:30 you'll have to caclulate in minutes, not hours. You can convert the hours and minutes to timestamps, check each time period, and then convert the seconds back to hours.

```
<?php
$number_of_overtime_hours = array();
$clockInTime = "18:30:00";
$clockOutTime = "19:30:00";
$startingPieces = explode(':',$clockInTime);
$finishingPieces = explode(':',$clockOutTime);
//Timestamps
$startTimestamp = mktime($startingPieces[0],$startingPieces[1],$startingPieces[2]);
$finishTimestamp = mktime($finishingPieces[0],$finishingPieces[1],$finishingPieces[2]);
//finish after 0h
if ($finishTimestamp < $startTimestamp){
    $finishTimestamp += 3600 * 24;
}
//set starting and ending points
$overtimePeriods = array(
    25 => array (17,19),
    50 => array (19,22),
    75 => array (22,24),
    100 => array (24,31)
);
$overtimeWork = array();
foreach ($overtimePeriods as $key => $val){
    //create Timestamps for overtime periods
    $beginTimestamp = mktime($val[0],0,0);
    $endTimestamp = mktime($val[1],0,0);
    //calculate hours inside the given period
    $overtimeWork[$key] = (min($finishTimestamp,$endTimestamp) - max($startTimestamp,$beginTimestamp)) / 3600;
    //negative values mean zero work in this period
    if ($overtimeWork[$key] < 0) $overtimeWork[$key] = 0;
}
var_dump($overtimeWork);
```